# Establishing Non-FK association between entities (preferably in the designer)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, associations, relationship

I cringe to ask this... as usual, I'm stuck with a legacy design beyond my control.

Incoming datafeed table (keyed to datafeed, line number, and file date):

```
DATAFEED_USER" 
(
  "DATAFEED_NM" VARCHAR2(32) NOT NULL ENABLE,
  "LINE_NBR" NUMBER(6,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
  "FILE_DT" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE,
  "NETWORK_ID" VARCHAR2(10),
  "PERNR" VARCHAR2(10),
  "COMPANY_CODE" VARCHAR2(5),
  "LOCAL_COMPANY_ID" VARCHAR2(12),
  // end identifier fields, begin user data
  "USER_TYPE" VARCHAR2(16),
  "LAST_NM" VARCHAR2(40),
  "FIRST_NM" VARCHAR2(40),
  ...
)
```

Table in our system (keyed to network ID):

```
USER_DESC 
(
  "NETWORK_ID" VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL ENABLE,
  "PERNR" CHAR(8),
  "COMPANY_CODE" VARCHAR2(4),
  "LOCAL_COMPANY_ID" VARCHAR2(12),
  // end identifier fields, begin user data
  "LAST_NM" VARCHAR2(40),
  "FIRST_NM" VARCHAR2(40),
  ...
)
```

I need the datafeed_user entities to have collections of matching user_desc records - records can match by network ID, PerNr, or Company Code + Local ID.  There's no FK relationship, because (1) new users will come in on the datafeed before we have a record of them, and (2) only the network ID is a PK in our system.

The relationships:

- Network ID:  Many datafeeds can send the same network ID; there will only be one match in our system - Many to 1.
- PerNr:  Only one datafeed users PerNrs, but they can match to multiple Network IDs in our system - 1 to Many
- Company Code/Local ID:  Each datafeed sends one Local ID, but they can match to multiple Network IDs in our system - 1 to Many

The datafeed processing looks at all potential matches to the database, chooses one using a set of business rules, and updates the matching record.  Users sent on more than one feed are flagged and not processed.  There are 250k+ records in our database, so I only want to pull down the matching records to update.  (I'd love to only pull down one, but then I'd have to push the business logic for matching records to the database)

How do I define a association/navigation property in the EF designer so that I can easily work with the related records?

I understand that what I'm after isn't a true relationship in db terms, so I'm open to alternatives.  The code I'm migrating uses typed datasets, which were extended to have custom properties (such as a collection of matched records).  I can't cleanly do that in the EF, because the .cs file is auto-generated.  The requirements are:

1. For each datafeed record, look at all records that match in our system by one of the three unique identifiers
2. Update the matching record in our system
3. Don't pull all 250k records down to update one (and definitely don't do that 1,000 times, once for each datafeed record)

Suggestions?

Comment: So cannot you just make a regular join between your tables based on described criterias?

Comment: @Evk, not sure what you mean... It's easy to do for the network ID, that's the PK in our table.   The Company Code/Legal Org is a many-to-many relationship; adding it to the designer or model doesn't seem easily doable.  A linq query against the USER_DESC entity where(one of the identifiers matches) *might* work, but (1) I'd have to update the record immediately, there's no DbSet on DATAFEED_USER to store the results, and (2) I can't seem to get away from "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression" generating the match criteria

Comment: I'm a bit lost then. Why there is no DbSet for datafeed? Maybe you can show how can you get desired result with raw sql query, without EF. Then we would have at least some idea of what's going on.